# MtpDevice.importFile and DocumentFile

Tags: android, android-sdcard, mtp, documentfile

`MtpDevice.importFile(int objectHandle, String destPath)` fails on 4.4 and above.  Is there a way to import from an MtpDevice with the SD card write lock?

Answer (score 0):

For the time being this is what I'm doing, though I'd love to avoid the double transfer:

```
            // KitKat and higher require the extra step of importing to the cache then moving
            if (Util.hasKitkat())
            {
                File tmp = new File(getExternalCacheDir(), name);
                mMtpDevice.importFile(objectHandle, tmp.getPath());
                success = FileUtil.moveFile(CameraImportActivity.this, tmp, endFile);
            }
            else
            {
                success = mMtpDevice.importFile(objectHandle, endFile.getPath());
            }
```